# Laravel pass variable from FirstController to SecondController

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

This is my two routes which pass variable on each view.

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('booking', 'BookingController');
```

I created a view which display the current product (ex. http://localhost:8000/product/15) using the ProductController.

Now i created another view to book this product then insert it (modal pop up) inside the product view using @include('partials.booking').

The problem is how can i pass the product id to the BookingController? It is possible?

Comment: you can put `$product->id` in a hidden field

Comment: then how can i pass the product id to the BookingController?

Comment: `partials.booking` is a form right?, so when submit it you can get it from BookingController

Comment: yes it is a form with a route of `booking.store`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on what framework you use in your frontend ( jquery etc. )

Usually your popup should somehow know what product it is referred to. You can do this for example like this

```
<!-- this is your html / blade -->
<div class="booking-popup">
  <button class="book" data-product="{{$product->id}}">Book Now!</button>
</div>
```

You can then use ajax and jquery for example to get the data attribute

Another option is to provide a form with a hidden field

```
<form action="/booking" method="post">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}" />
   <input type="submit" value="Book Now!" />
</form>
```

If you use the laravel html collective you can simplify it even more

**EDIT**

Since your Bookings actually belong to a product you could also rearrange your resources so that a booking is create with the route

```
/product/5/booking (POST)
```

You could then simply access the product id as parameter of the route

**EDIT 2**
To access it from your controller simply ( case of hidde form input )

```
public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  dd($request->input('product_id');
}
```

If you defined it via route simply go for whatever you set as placeholder

```
Route::post('product/{product}/book', 'BookingController@store');
```

Controller then:

```
public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $product) {
   dd($product)
}
```

Comment: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\BookingController::store()
this is the controller `store(Request $request, $id)`

i used data-product="{{$product->id}}" to pass the id, but i got this error

Comment: Thanks. I just used `<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}" />` then get the request value `$request->product_id;`

Answer (score 1):

Include your model page as `@include('partials.booking', ['product'=>$product])`

Change your form action to 
`<form action="{{url('product/'.$product->id.'/booking')}}" method="post">` and most important add _token hidden field if your CSRF middleware is enabled.

Change your route to
`Route::post('product/{product_id}/booking', 'BookingController@store');`